# Swift: Protocol 'Set' can only be used as a generic constraint because it has Self or associated type requirements

Tags: swift, data-structures, set, swift-protocols, abstract-data-type

So, I'm trying to implement a version of the Set ADT on Swift as practice and when I try to implement the Set Interface (or protocol in swift), I get the following error: "Protocol 'Set' can only be used as a generic constraint because it has Self or associated type requirements". Heres what I got so far coded:

```
public protocol Set{
    associatedtype E

    func add(elm : E)
    func remove(elm : E) -> Bool
    func clear()
    func isMember(elm : E) -> Bool
    func size() -> Int
    func isEmpty() -> Int
    func isSubset(S2 : Set) -> Bool
    func union(S2 : Set) -> Set?
    func intersection(S2 : Set) -> Set?
    func difference(S2 : Set) -> Set?
}
```

Comment: Don't name you protocol to the same as a built in type, this will only leads to confusion and in worst case errors

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can define some Set-like protocol as follows:

```
public protocol MySet{
    associatedtype Element

    func add(elm : Element)
    func remove(elm : Element) -> Bool
    func clear()
    func isMember(elm : Element) -> Bool
    func size() -> Int
    func isEmpty() -> Int
    func isSubset(S2 : Self) -> Bool
    func union(S2 : Self) -> Self?
    func intersection(S2 : Self) -> Self?
    func difference(S2 : Self) -> Self?
}
```

But I'm not sure it works as ADT as you expect.
As in the error message you get, in Swift, protocols with associated type (or having `Self`) *can only be used as a generic constraint*.

Swift protocols may not work like *interface* in some other Object-oriented languages in some cases.

You say this *as practice*, then this can be a good practice to learn how Swift protocols work.